In PrusaSlicer, does a pause on a layer happen before that layer is printed, or after?
In PrusaSlicer (and I assume Slic3r), when you add a pause, the pause is "on" a layer, so it's not clear when it happens relative to that layer. Is it at the end? The beginning?
For instance, is this pause correct to insert magnets into the holes before they're closed at Z=2.8 mm? The left shows up to 2.6 mm, and the right up to 2.8 mm, when the holes are closed.

Looking at the exported GCode, it seems correct, but it feels wrong based on the visualization (i.e. it shows them closed up).
G1 Z2.6 F720  ; it's printing stuff at Z2.6
G1 E.8 F1500
   [...a few lines...]
;LAYER_CHANGE ; change, before_change, after_change stuff...
;Z:2.8
;HEIGHT:0.2
   [...a couple lines...]
;PAUSE_PRINT
M117 Place magnets in slots and resume printing
M601
M486 S-1
M486 S2
G1 X216.192 Y65.471
G1 Z2.8 F720   ; then it starts doing stuff at Z2.8
G1 E.8 F1500


The pause is before printing the layer at 2.8 mm.

Select Insert pause print (M601)
The pause will be inserted before the selected layer is being printed

Source
It is best explained by the G-code, but know that your slicer presents the layer as if it is printed, you can play the creation of the layer at 2.8 mm where you see it will start with showing the layer at 2.6 mm where the openings are not closed yet, and build upon that layer.
You also see this in the generated code, it first lays down layer 13 at 2.6 mm, then initiates a pause, to finally advancing to the next layer and finish building layer 14 at 2.8 mm.
